# Tensorflow - indexing according to batch position

Tags: python, tensorflow, indexing

I'm working on masking r-cnn and I have a problem with indexing the masks according to labels.

Here's what I want to achieve: I have a tensor `(?,28,28,c)`, where `?` is unknown batch_size, "28x28" are 2d coordinates and `c` stands for different labels, then I have a list of indices (basically my label predictions) (?,) of `int32`. Now I want to extract the masks for a given label according to batch index -> make it a `(?,28,28,1)` tensor.

I tried `self.masks_sigmoids = tf.gather(self.final_conv, self.label_predictions, axis=3)`, but the shape remained the same.

I also looked at `tf.gather_nd` here http://www.riptutorial.com/tensorflow/example/29069/how-to-use-tf-gather-nd, and I guess this is the right path, but I don't know how to incorporate that I want the indices according to batch index (in numpy `(b_i,:,:,c_i)`)

I also get a feeling that my question is somewhat similar to [Batched 4D tensor Tensorflow indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505926/batched-4d-tensor-tensorflow-indexing), though my problem seems less complicated. However, that question is old in terms of the quick development of tensorflow, so I'm asking for a possibly better, more clear solution. EDIT: Even a dirty solution might beneficial as I didn't get the question in the linked SO (already wrote a comment asking to clarify the question), thus I don't get much from the only answer. It might be beneficial for the community as well, because this question is simpler, which means it would demonstrate the solution more clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution 1: more generic

You can look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43677545/7456923), it's basically the same problem as yours, with different dimensions.

The solution described there is to create a `[?, 28, 28, 4]`-shaped tensor `indices` where `indices[i, x, y, :] = [i, x, y, self.label_predictions[i]]`, and then use `tf.gather_nd`:

```
self.masks_sigmoids = tf.gather_nd(self.final_conv, indices=indices)
```

Building the `indices` is not very elegant, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43677545/7456923) (with one more dimension for you), but easy in itself.

## Solution 2: A bit more elegant and adapted to your problem

This solution is very similar to the first one, but avoids creating the `[x, y]` part of `indices`. The idea is to use the slicing capabilities of gather_nd to avoid writing `[x, y]` in `indices` for each `(i, x, y)`, by transposing the data before gathering it. I'll put the whole code here, including how to create `indices` and how to test:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

N_CHANNELS = 5
pl=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32, shape=(None, 28, 28, N_CHANNELS))

# Indices we'll use. batch_size = 4 here.
label_predictions = tf.constant([0, 2, 0, 3])

# Indices of shape [?, 2], with indices[i] = [i, self.label_predictions[i]],
# which is easy to do with tf.range() and tf.stack()
indices = tf.stack([tf.range(tf.size(label_predictions)), label_predictions], axis=-1)
# [[0, 0], [1, 2], [2, 0], [3, 3]]

transposed = tf.transpose(pl, perm=[0, 3, 1, 2])
gathered = tf.gather_nd(transposed, indices)  # Should be of shape (4, 2, 3)
result = tf.expand_dims(gathered, -1)

initial_value = np.arange(4*28*28*N_CHANNELS).reshape((4, 28, 28, N_CHANNELS))
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
res = sess.run(result, feed_dict={pl: initial_value})
# print(res)

print("checking validity")
for i in range(4):
    for x in range(28):
        print(x)
        for y in range(28):
            assert res[i, x, y, 0] == initial_value[i, x, y, indices[i, 1].eval()]
print("All assertions passed")
```

Comment: I've juste taken a look at the thread you've linked to, the solution seems to be essentially the same: building `indices` and using `gather_nd`. Be careful though: they use `tf.pack()`, which is deprecaetd and was replaced with `tf.stack()`

Comment: This is a great and elegant approach. Thanks a lot!